# I have a problem with an approved edit; what do I do?

Tags: discussion

This question (not mine) just got edited, and the edit was approved:

[How to wrap the newly input text into the following already-existed span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686556/how-to-wrap-the-newly-input-text-into-the-following-already-existed-span-tag)

I had edited the question a while ago. I fixed some formatting errors in code:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12052657

Then it was edited to fix further errors in code, but I personally think it should not have happened (I'll explain):

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2459706

Here's the full revisions log:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36686556/revisions

I think the problem with the two edits after mine is that it changes the meaning of the code:

1. Since the `<span id="6>` was added programmatically, it could be intentional/a bug; so I asked the OP in the comments, which hasn't received any response yet.
2. Even though adding returns between spans makes for better readability, I held off in doing that, since it's an inline element, and the returns are going to show in the final page.

Are my assumptions correct? What do I do if yes?

Comment: *Put your spans on seperate [sic] rows.* Yeah, that user apparently likes to add line breaks to markup that is not theirs. This looks harmless enough, but adding the `<br>` elements may invalidate existing answers or produce answers that do not address the questioner's markup properly. I rolled back that edit. (I see Cerbrus also rolled back yours, I won't address that.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The other edit added quotes to the OP's code where they were missing. That was more malicious (I rolled back Mohammad Anini's edit). Currently, the question has cst1992's edit as it's current revision.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got confused about the edit owners. Oh well.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm confessing to plagiarizing the comment you left on [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36686556/444991), albeit with the addition of an `@` to the editor in question, so that he'll see the comment...

Comment: _*Flags for plagiarism*_ 

Comment: declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it :O

Comment: The Approve/Reject ratio of some of the reviewers suggests that they were robo-approving.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Only if this ratio is correct. There was a bug which caused in correct numbers in the history. I don't know if this was fixed already.

Comment: @Tom OK, didn't know that. I'm certainly hoping some of these numbers are incorrect. Otherwise the moderators may want to look into the reviewing history of these users.

Comment: @Tom I am 99.9% certain that bug has since been fixed.